# Android: How to detect if a user is running 6.0.1, not 6.0

Tags: java, android, sdk, version

I am developing an Android app which uses many of the new Unicode Emoji.
I have tested the app on both Android 6.0 and 6.0.1, and I have discovered that because the app uses the new emoji and only 6.0.1 supports the new emoji, that the app doesn't work on Android 6.0.

I would like to set the minimum SDK version to 6.0.1, but there is no way to differentiate 6.0 and 6.0.1 since both are SDK level 23.

Is there a way to detect if a user is running 6.0.1, not 6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hope that all devices that once had 6.0 have been upgraded to 6.0.1 by now.

That being said, you can try [examining `Build.VERSION.RELEASE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#RELEASE), though some manufacturers might tinker with this.

Answer (score 0):

Check [`android.os.Build.VERSION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html).

> - `RELEASE`:  The user-visible version string. E.g., "1.0" or "3.4b5".